# How to do a check for the insert in a table of a maximum of attribute with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing a univerity project for a database of drug prescription

I have the table prescription

```
CRETE TABLE Prescription(
     Code_P VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY, 
     Patient_ID VARCHAR(100) REFERENCES PATIENT,
     Date_prescription TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

The other table:

```
CREATE TABLE Description_Prescription(
     Code_Presc VARCHAR(100),
     Drug_ID VARCHAR(100),
     Doctor_ID VARCHAR(100),
     Quantity_Drug NUMERIC(6,3) NOT NULL
     PRIMARY KEY (Code_Presc, Drug_ID),
         FOREIGN KEY (Code_Presc) REFERENCES Prescription,
         FOREIGN KEY (Drug_ID) REFERENCES DRUG,
         FOREIGN KEY (Doctor_ID) REFERENCES Doctor
);
```

my problem is how to do a check when a doctor insert a drug on a prescription. I mean A doctor for each prescription can insert a maximum of 5 drugs.

How can I do this?

Comment: trigger would be the easiest (if not the only) solution

Comment: Does a prescription with a `Quantity_Drug`of zero count as a prescription?

Comment: no Quantity_drug you take count only of the number of each drug I mean for example: 1 Tachipirina, 3 Ibroprufene, 4 Vicodin, 2 Natrexone.

Comment: And what *is* the number of drug? The number of pills? The total  weight in Kg?

Comment: no Quantity_drug you take count only of the number of each drug I mean for example: 1 Tachipirina, 3 Ibroprufene, 4 Vicodin, 2 Natrexone. What I want is a check to say not insert more of 5 type of drugs (example: Tachipirina, Imbroprofene, Vicodin, Natrexone, Aspirin, Voltaren --> ERROR you inserted more of five drugs)

Comment: Number of drug is the number of pack/boxes of drugs. In Italy drugs are sell in boxes not Bulky pills. For example in a box of Aspirin there are 5 pills but for example you need 10 pills so 2 box of aspirin